# .NET: HttpClient object seems to ignore certificate authority for server certificate validation: Do I miss something?

Tags: .net, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have the following situation: I use a System.Net.Http.HttpClient (.Net Fx 4.7.1) object accessing an URL which uses SSL/TLS. The server's certificate shall be trusted because it is signed by company's PKI infrastructure and my collegues have updated the client computer's certificate store to trust it.

However, if I open the URL with a Browser (IE/Chrome), the connection is trusted, when I access the same URL with my HttpClient object, I get the follow error chain:

AggregateException: One or more Errors occurred.
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
WebException: The underlying Connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

It seems, that the Browser (Internet Explorer/Chrome) does have another 'validation procedure' as the HttpClient object.

If make a test to https://google.com all works fine.

Do I need to tell the HttpClient object that it need to take care of trusted authorities stored in computer account?
On the other hand I didn't find any property this for.

I know how to bypass the exception with ServerCertificateVAlidateionCallback, but since I need a secure and trusted connection, this is only a solution for testing.

Any ideas? very apreciated!
Have good time Folks!

Comment: If you create the validation calback you can inspect the SslPolicyFlags and X509Chain object to find out why it failed.  But if IE says it's good then .NET should say it's good (unless the server is multi-homed and the cert is chosen with SNI, because maybe .NET isn't setting that option yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, bartonjs

Solved - Found out what I did wrong: the certificate and its chain was all good, my mistake was, that I still had subscribed to **ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback(...)** and there I currently returned *false*, because I thought, the ServerCertificateValidationCallback would only be called when the certificate validation fails, but actually the method is designed to do an own validation and so, of course, it's always called.

Thank you to point me to the right direction - this was a right the bullseye ...